# Rails Heroku Cloudflare Setup - www won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have a rails app that's configured to force SSL:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```

It is then deployed to Heroku (free tier), where I configured to add my custom domain.

On Cloudflare, I only have these 2 records:

```
CNAME  example.com  example.herokuapp.com
CNAME  www          example.com
```

I also set the SSL option to be `full`.

My understanding is that, when people visit my webiste at `www.example.com`, they get redirected to the apex (non-www) url.

However, now whenever I visit the `www` version, it shows me the Heroku's No Such App page.

I have no idea what I did wrong and have tried all sorts of ways I have found online for a whole week. Hope someone can help me out, thanks!

Comment: Can you please try updating cname www record as follows:

CNAME  www  example.herokuapp.com

Comment: @svikramjeet It still shows me the heroku's No Such App page

Comment: Have you added www.example.com in heroku domains as well?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response from heroku 'No such App' found, please confirm if `www.example.com` is added as custom domain under settings?